# How to create Bluemix accounts (IDs) using an api?

Tags: api, ibm-cloud, account

I'd like to create Bluemix accounts programmatically (for e.g. using an api). Basically, trying to accomplish the 'Create Account' functionality in this page:
https://console.ng.bluemix.net/registration/ via code/api. Is that possible? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

## NO.                   (At least not legally, no.)

The bottom of the page says:

> By clicking Create Account, I accept the Bluemix privacy policy and
>   Bluemix terms.

They want you to come there, and manually sign up for an account, and AGREE to their terms.  I don't think they'd let a 3rd party automate past their ToS/EULA.

I can't think of any legitimate reason to skip this page except to try to cheat IBM's ToS.

Comment: Thanks! Sounds like this ability to create an account with an api would be a feature request (the request is for something like this: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users#create_user )

Answer (score 0):

Creating an account on Bluemix creates an IBM ID involving IBM authentication agents and a serie of redirects to flow.
Moreover you have to accept Bluemix ToS and so on.
For all these points (and also for QoS reason) you cannot create a Bluemix account programmatically.
Once the account is created, you could interact with the whole Bluemix architecture through its REST Apis

Comment: In addition to what has already been said, each account must be associated with a valid, unique email address. You must log into that email account and validate the new Bluemix account through the email that is sent to you from IBM.

Comment: Thanks! Sounds like this ability to create an account with an api would be a feature request with Bluemix (the request is for something like this: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users#create_user )